# possibility of 16bit UUID rather than 128bit UUID for bluetooth service in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I am writing an android app which creates bluetooth connection with external non-android device (e.g., custom bluetooth device). In my android app i am creating UUID for my service which is 128bit. When android app is **listening with 128bit UUID, if external device is connecting with same 128bit UUID**, the connection was successful.

If the external device is connecting with only **16bit and assuming the remaining bits as bluetooth base UUID**, connection was unsuccessful.

My question is **Can we change the 128bit UUID to 16bit UUID in android bluetooth ?**

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no way as far as I can tell.
But you can make sure that the base UUID used by the external device is correct , then it should connect to the android app that registers with the 128 bit UUID.

Comment: thanks for responding to my question. I need to provide 16 bit UUID in android app, it seem to be not possible with your answer.